# Android: How to make a custom view take only the available screen space?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have two custom views, which i want to layout vertically.
The first view is a sort of playing board, which is a square. The square scales easily and can adapt to almost any available space.

The second view is a subclass of `[TableLayout][1]` which holds several `Button`s. The number of rows/columns is determined at runtime.

To ease explaining, i'll call the first view *board* and the second one *table*.

I want *board* to be displayed at the top of the screen and *table* should go right below it. *Table* should take the vertical space it needs (which basically depends on the number of rows). *Board* should set it's square edge size to the minimum of the available width and the available height, i.e. scale down.

I tried to achieve this using a `[RelativeLayout][2]` like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="@dimen/default_padding"
                >

    <some.package.Table
        android:id="@+id/table"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/default_padding"
        />

    <some.package.Board
        android:id="@+id/board"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/table"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

With this approach I had hoped that the *table* would be measured first and the remaining available screen height would be passed as maximum (i.e. `AT_MOST`) height spec to the `onMeasure` of *board*. This assumption appears to be wrong.

When I use this layout, the board seems to be resized to zero size, i.e. it is not rendered.

When I turn things around like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="@dimen/default_padding"
                >

    <some.package.Board
        android:id="@+id/board"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        />

    <some.package.Table
        android:id="@+id/table"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/default_padding"
        android:layout_below="@id/board"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The *board* takes up too much vertical space and the *table* gets cut off at the bottom

In both cases *board* get's the display width as `AT_MOST` width spec and the display height (minus status bar and action bar height) as `AT_MOST` height spec. So my `onMeasure` implementation takes the minimum of both as square size which does not leave enough room for the table view.

Could anyone give me a heads up how to go about this, please?
Do I maybe need to add a nested layout? Or work with layout weights? - I've refrained from doing so, as weights are for relative sizing in my understanding.

Thanks & kind regards

---

**Edit after Gabe's answer:**

After trying Gabe's suggestion I logged some data in the `onMeasure` methods of *board* and *table*:

```
table: wM=EXACTLY minW=0 ws=736 hM=EXACTLY minH=0 hs=1006
board: wM=AT_MOST minW=0 ws=736 hM=AT_MOST minH=0 hs=1006
board: wM=EXACTLY minW=0 ws=736 hM=EXACTLY minH=0 hs=1006
table: wM=EXACTLY minW=0 ws=736 hM=AT_MOST minH=0 hs=0
I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 206 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 305K, 8% free 4880K/5252K, paused 103ms, total 105ms
table: wM=EXACTLY minW=0 ws=736 hM=EXACTLY minH=0 hs=1006
board: wM=AT_MOST minW=0 ws=736 hM=AT_MOST minH=0 hs=1006
board: wM=EXACTLY minW=0 ws=736 hM=EXACTLY minH=0 hs=1006
table: wM=EXACTLY minW=0 ws=736 hM=AT_MOST minH=0 hs=0
```

wM is the width mode from the `MeasureSpec`, minW is `getSuggestedMinimumWidth()`, ws is the width size from the `MeasureSpec`.
Same applies for hM, minH and hs.

I have *not* overridden `onMeasure` in *table* (well yes, I have, but it just logs the data and calls `super.onMeasure()`). The behaviour implemented in `board.onMeasure()` is described above.

I'm still puzzled...

---

**Edit after kha's answer:**

kha's suggestion worked. The working XML-layout is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="@dimen/default_padding"
                >

    <some.package.Table
        android:id="@+id/table"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/default_padding"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />

    <some.package.Board
        android:id="@+id/board"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/table"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The logging output is now:

```
board: wM=AT_MOST minW=0 ws=736 hM=AT_MOST minH=0 hs=1006
table: wM=EXACTLY minW=0 ws=736 hM=EXACTLY minH=0 hs=1006
table: wM=EXACTLY minW=0 ws=736 hM=AT_MOST minH=0 hs=1006
board: wM=EXACTLY minW=0 ws=736 hM=EXACTLY minH=0 hs=702
I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 118 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
board: wM=AT_MOST minW=0 ws=736 hM=AT_MOST minH=0 hs=1006
table: wM=EXACTLY minW=0 ws=736 hM=EXACTLY minH=0 hs=1006
table: wM=EXACTLY minW=0 ws=736 hM=AT_MOST minH=0 hs=1006
board: wM=EXACTLY minW=0 ws=736 hM=EXACTLY minH=0 hs=702
```

Comment: Just a thought (I don't have access to Android now so it's all a guess) but what happens if you move and change the `android:layout_below="@id/board"` to `android:layout_above="@id/table"` on your other layout. Do this in conjunction with setting `android:alignParentBottom=true` on your table layout.  Hard to help without eclipse but that may work if you get lucky :).

Comment: This is a working solution. If you post this as answer, I'll mark it as correct. Thank you very much :-)

Comment: Was just a guess so I'm happy it actually worked :). I'll post it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Move and change the

```
android:layout_below="@id/board"
```

to

```
android:layout_above="@id/table"
```

on your other layout.

Do this in conjunction with setting `android:alignParentBottom=true` on your table layout.

Answer (score 0):

The order of views in a relative layout determines the z ordering if they overlap, not the order they're drawn in.  Also, weights only do things for LinearLayout, not Relative.

The second XML is almost correct-  it will measure out the table, let it take as much room as it wants, then layout the board below it.  Change the height of the board to match_parent and it should work-  it will force it to take up no more than the remaining room.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but sadly, this is not the solution.

Comment: Done just that in the past.  Unless your onMeasure is doing something weird it ought to work.

Comment: Hi Gabe, I'll edit my original question to include logging output of the measurement process.